# Azure: How to create the WADLogsTable for capturing diagnostics code?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, diagnostics

I have a worker role that I would like to get diagnoistics feedback on... after adding the appropriate connection string to the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg and the following code:

```
//DiagnosticMonitor.Start("DiagnosticsConnectionString");
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);
diagConfig.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start("DiagnosticsConnectionString", diagConfig);
CrashDumps.EnableCollection(true);
```

When I call "System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("test log") I expect to be able to find the record in the WADLogsTable of the target Azure Storage Account.  Howver, the table doesn't exist- how is it created?  None of the documentation I've read covers this.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to set a log level filter, like:

```
diagConfig.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;
```

I have a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083577/how-to-log-exceptions-caught-in-wcf-service-deployed-on-azure/3085625#3085625).

Note that occasionally, in the simulation environment, the tables don't get created immediately.